# Angular Pipes with template strings that are inserted through [innerHTML]

Tags: javascript, html, angular, template-literals, template-strings

I was trying to implement `ngx-translate` in one of the recently completed angular projects. In the project we have a component that renders HTML files inside a certain div through `innerHTML`. Now as I am planning to use pipe to transform the HTML file text as per the language I wanted to bind the texts inside the HTML string with template strings like so:

```
     <tr>
                    <th class="border-top-0">${this.test}</th>
    // the above is just to verify is pipe works as it will later be changed to:
// ${'HELLO' | translate:param} 
                    <th class="border-top-0">Description</th>
                    <th class="border-top-0">Action?</th>
                </tr>
```

The way I prepare the HTML file to be rendered inside a component:

component.ts:

```
 this._httpClient.get(path, { responseType: "text" }).subscribe(
    data => {
      const htmlStr = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data);
      this.htmlString = eval('`' + htmlStr + '`');
    });
});
```

.HTML:

```
 <div  [innerHTML]="htmlString">    </div>
```

Till the above-mentioned steps, it works fine and the HTML is rendered as expected but
now when I try to use any kind of pipe with it for example: `${this.test | uppercase}` it gives the following error:

```
uppercase is not defined
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: You can use transform in component ts file like`constructor(private upperCasePipe: UpperCasePipe) { this.variable = upperCasePipe.transform(this.variable); }`

Comment: @ciekals11 sorry for the confusion i have updated my questions. I only meant to show it as an example but when I use the translate pipe I am not feeding any specific variable  so it is not possible to use transform before hand.

Comment: Hmm. I think (haven't tested it) you can still use `pipeName.transform()` like `<th class="border-top-0">{{ translationPipe.transform('General Kenobi') }}</th>` which is not ideal solution. But a solution nonetheless

Comment: But the double braces `{{` cannot be worked when passed in as an innerHTML string. it just displays as it is.

Comment: Ah sorry. i meant `${}` instead of `{{}}`.

Comment: What's with this syntax `${this.test}` ?

Comment: Even you have customised interpolation `$` should not work as it is reserved by Angular

Comment: Why use `this` keyword in component's template?

Comment: @ciekals11 Thanks i guess `${translationPipe.transform('General Kenobi')}` works. I could not test with the translationPipe right away but I did try with the uppercase pipe and it worked fine so hoping the translation does too. Minor tweak I had to do was:
`${this.uPipe.transform('General Kenobi')}`. Thanks a lot for the solution. Can you add it as the answer itself so I can mark it as accepted

Comment: @Vikas he is using `${ this.test }` instead of `{{ test }}` because it is not template as you refers to it but string that contains html tag that is placed in html via `innerHTML`. Read question.

Comment: @Vikas the html that contains `${ this.test }` is not part of a component but rather an individual HTML that I render inside a component through `[innerHTML]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. I think (haven't tested it) you can still use pipeName.transform() like:

```html
<th class="border-top-0">
    ${ this.translationPipe.transform('General Kenobi') }
</th>
```

which is not ideal solution.
But a solution nonetheless.